# ¿Cómo optimizaríais un grid de 5 imágenes con php?

Tags: php, pdf, optimización, algoritmos

estoy tratando de hacer un pdf con php y la librería fpdf.

El caso es que necesito hacer un collage de 5 imágenes tal que así
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJ7n.jpg
(Solo que la imagen grande en el centro y las chicas a los lados)

Las imágenes van a ser proporcionalmente iguales y no se pueden recortar ni dedormar, por lo que siendo:

X: ancho imagen grande
Y: alto imagen grande
x: ancho imágenes chicaa
y: alto imágenes chicas 
z: el margen interno

Se tendría que cumplir las siguientes condiciones

El ancho de las 2 imágenes chicas más el ancho de la imagen grande más los dos márgenes internos tiene que ser igual a 262 mm

1) 2x + 2z + X = 262

El alto de la imagen grande tiene que ser igual al alto de las dos imágenes chicas más el margen interno

2) 2y + z = Y

Las imágenes chicas y la grande son proporcionales

3) Y / X = y / x

Despejando he llegado a esta ecuación

2zy - 262y - zx = 0

Pero ahí me he quedado. No se como continuar ni si es posible una solución optimizada para cuadrar las imágenes en el grid.

Me encantaría una solución donde el margen interno sea siempre 5mm pero eso creo que es imposible.

Si no fuera posible nada de lo anterior, me gustaría preguntaros por un método en el que podamos recortar verticalmente las imágenes chicas y que la z sea a siempre 5mm
Podríamos tener una ecuación para saber las X,  x,  Y, y de modo que haya que recortar lo menos posible y este optimizado.

Supongo que habría que hacerlo derivando pero no se me ocurre nada.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda o recomendaciones de librerías, ya sea en php o cualquier otro idioma que hagan algo parecido.

**Edit**
Olvidé mencionar que la proporción de las imágenes, aunque todas las de un pdf sean iguales, pueden variar de un pdf a otro

Comment: Yo lo veo como dibujar una tabla de 3 columnas por 2 filas. La celda (1,1) ocupa 2 filas, de modo que está mezclada con la celda (2,1), y las celdas (1,2), (1,3), (2,2) y (2,3) servirán para colocar las otras imágenes, con esto te ahorras redimensionar las imágenes puesto que sólo decides el tamaño de las celdas. Ahora, si quieres evitar todos los cálculos, puedes crear una tabla de 4 columnas por 2 filas y la primera celda (1,1) estará unida a las celda (1,2), (2,1) y (2,2) y las otras imágenes estarán ubicadas en las otras celdas.

Comment: Listo, me ha ayudado mucho tu respuesta. He tenido que preocuparme un poco de los bordes ya que en la anchura de la imagen central tenía que  tenerse en cuenta también que en la altura se meten los bordes internos para mantener las proporciones. Pero todo guay. Gracias

Comment: @HusseinLababidi Si has dado con la respuesta, por favor, compártela a la comunidad.

Comment: @ drielnox ha sido muy sencillo en realidad, simplemente he tenido que crear una tabla en html con las condiciones que @LuiggiMendoza me dijo (que las imagenes pequeñas midan 2/8 de lo que mida el total de la tabla y la imagen grande 4/8)

Luego lo he puesto en el pdf usando este script: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php